# Cloud Formation template add ingress rule to existing security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

**Problem scope**

I have an application built using multiple cloud formation templates. They need to interact with each other but are too large/complicated to build in one template.

**Detail of scenario**

Imagine there were only two template (there are significantly more)

- Template A
- Template B

Template A creates a security group (security group A) with itself as the only ingress rule. It is applied to a series of hosts in this template that perform the same function.

Template B creates another security group (Security group B) and a number of hosts (in an elastic beanstalk).

**Question**

I want to add an ingress rule to **Security Group A** for traffic from **Security Group B** using **cloud formation**?

**What have I tried**

I have looked through the documentation, I want to create a security group Ingress rule and associate it with security group A but that doesn't seem to be viable as far as I can see - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-rule.html

**Other alternatives**

I could just use the CIDR range of the hosts that are in Security Group B as that is known before any of this is built (all in VPC's with separate subnets) however I feel there must be a better more secure way than accepting traffic from a cidr range.

Answer (score 1):

AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress is the answer.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html

Pass the security group A ID into Template B as a parameter SGBase. Then create a resource like this.

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Resources": {
        "SGBaseIngress": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress",
            "Properties": {
                "GroupName": { "Ref": "SGBase" },
                "IpProtocol": "tcp",
                "FromPort": "80",
                "ToPort": "80",
                "SourceSecurityGroupName": { "Ref": "SGBase" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```